# Playa not playing with Zurb Foundation css

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I'm getting a conflict when using Playa with Zurb Foundation.

I have the playa field in a exp:channel:form tag and it works fine in the current site, which doesn't use foundation, but in the responsive site that I'm building using Zurb Foundation framework, Playa just seems to hang the page load.

Taking the Playa field out, the page loads and behaves fine.

Taking the foundation.css out the page loads and behaves fine.

Putting them together and everything slows down.

Anyone come across this ?

Andy D

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Playa and Zurb Foundation without problem. Try to verify if no have conflict between css class, id in the both css files. For sure there could have hierarchy problems, or class or id with the same name in the both css files (Zurb and Playa).

Comment: Thanks Stephane - I've checked all the Playa css and it all seems to be named with a playa_ prefix so I don't think it's that. However I've just discovered the problem seems to be just when using Safari on OSX. No probs in Firefox and Chrome as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was just with an earlier version of Safari. Updating Safari sorted it out.

Comment: Really this problem seemed very strange. Can give headache this problem came from the browser version.

Comment: Yes, was banging my head against the wall - never mind. Thanks for the feedback.